# Drupal Context doesn't work on the view pages

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I am working with the context module to display a block on specific pages. The problem, that I am facing that the context works just fine on the first page of the view, however, the block disappears on the others view pages (page 2 and up).

Anyone knows what causes this weird behavior?

Comment: Could you explain in more details? I don't see what you mean. What you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a view (MyView) Page. I want to show a block (MyBlock) only on the view (MyView) Pages. I have used the context module and it shows the the block (MyBlock) on the first page of the view (MyView) but not on the other pages of the view (I am using the pager to display 10 records per page). For Some reason, the context module fails to recognize that the paged pages of the view (MyView) are part of the same context.

Comment: I actually don't know this [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module (if this is what you're saying about), but let's see. What path your page (MyView) has? Does your block (MyBlock) have **Page specific visibility settings** to **Show on only the listed pages**? If yes, could you say this options?

Comment: the visibility settings are controlled via the context module. Using the context module you can determine that you want a view/block/menu appear on certain pages. The context module is working just fine for http://mywebsite.local/the-products/33 but no for http://mywebsite.local/the-products/33?field_company_tid=All&field_requirement_tid=All&field_product_type_tid=All&field_body_part_tid=All&field_product_time_tid=All

Comment: have you tried using the wildcard in the path settings in context? it should be something like `the-products/*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and I saw here: http://drupal.org/node/904416#comment-3725344 a solution.

I have installed the module http://drupal.org/project/purl and everything goes find (no configuration)

Hope this help you